# I am not able to sent email in wordpress website using cloud amazon hosting

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

Thank you in advance for help !

I am trying to send email on WordPress website but the email sending function not working. Please let me know the best way so i can able to sent email.
Thanks

Comment: To get a real answer, not guessing you need to provide more information. At least tell us if request to send mail hits CloudFront - e.g sent from browser at all (it is not clear from your description), and if it hits your origin server. Also if it is - what errors do you see when directly calling mail() on the server.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am sending the email using function wp_email(). but It was not sent. My hosting at amazon cloud server.

Comment: are you expecting a good advise for such limited information? To be more specific - are you using CloudFront in from of your server? Your tag suggests it but you didn't mention this anywhere. Are you using EC2 server to host your wordpress site? When calling wp_email() what is the result? Is there anything in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You either have to signup for SES for sending email or use services like sendgrid or mandrill. Without either of these services you cannot send an email on amazon

Comment: Either simple PHP email function mail() not able to send email. Are you sure it is above issue ?